# What code can I add to my example that will make it continue taking photos?

Tags: android, camera, photo, back

My objective is for the app to take a picture and then you click the button again, and it returns to the camera ready to take another shot after reviewing it? I only want the program to stop if the home button is clicked. or the back button. Code is posted below

```
package com.example;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class CameraDemo extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "CameraDemo";
Camera camera;
Preview preview;
Button buttonClick;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    preview = new Preview(this);
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);

    buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
    buttonClick.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        }
    });

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");
}


ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    public void onShutter() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
    }
};

/** Handles data for raw picture */
PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
    }
};

/** Handles data for jpeg picture */
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            // write to local sandbox file system
            outStream = CameraDemo.this.openFileOutput(String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()), 0); 
            // Or write to sdcard
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));  
            outStream.write(data);
            outStream.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
    }
};

}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: What line of code will ensure that after the button is clicked that it will take the picture, view it, then go back to taking pictures